# Java won't display an overwritten image

Tags: java, swing, caching, imageicon

I have an image that is read from a folder at the start of the program. The program will download a new image from the internet and overwrite the old image, same filepath and same name, but the image displayed is the old image. When I exit and reload the program, the new image is displayed. I know that the image isn't changing because I also tried to create a new ImageIcon from the filepath and display it in a JDialog after downloading and it's still the old image. Any ideas?

Comment: The old image may be held in a cache, preventing it from being changed. How do you read it in? You should use `ImageIO.read(...)`.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add some code snippets of what you're doing.

Comment: I just download and overwrite an image at filePath, then do JLabel myL = new ImageIcon(filePath); JDialog jd = new JDialog(); jd.add(myL); and the jdialog displays the old image. when i exit and restart the program the new image is displayed.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels using ImageIO.read() worked thanks!
however it's only the jdialog that displays correctly. the original frame still shows the old image even though i've called frame.validate(); frame.repaint();

Comment: You may still have a reference to the old image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> however it's only the jdialog that displays correctly. the original frame still shows the old image even though i've called frame.validate(); frame.repaint();

Reading an image into memory does not cause the component to reference the new image. You still need to add the Icon to any component that used the old image.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ImageReload extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JLabel timeLabel;
    JLabel imageLabel;
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("timeLabel.jpg");

    public ImageReload()
    {
        timeLabel = new JLabel( new Date().toString() );
        imageLabel = new JLabel( timeLabel.getText() );
        getContentPane().add(timeLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        getContentPane().add(imageLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        timeLabel.setText( new Date().toString() );

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    String imageName = "timeLabel.jpg";
                    BufferedImage image = ScreenImage.createImage(timeLabel);
                    ScreenImage.writeImage(image, imageName);

                    //  This works using ImageIO

//                  imageLabel.setIcon( new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read( new File(imageName) ) ) );

                    //  Or you can flush the image

                    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(imageName);
                    icon.getImage().flush();
                    imageLabel.setIcon( icon );
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println( e );
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ImageReload frame = new ImageReload();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: oh... i just ended up deleting the component from the frame and readding it as a new jlabel lol

Comment: Then post that on your own as an answer to your own question and select it as your answer, or check this one off as a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @ALee,  `i just ended up deleting the component from the frame and readding it as a new jlabel` - Why? I just showed you how to replace the Icon.

Comment: i was chasing another bug at the time, but i've switched to your method now

Answer (score -1):

ended up deleting the old component from the frame, and readding the label with the new image

```
frame.remove(picLabel);
BufferedImage b = ImageIO.read(new File(attemptedFilePath));
picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(b));
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.weightx = 0.5;
c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 0;
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
c.insets = new Insets(10,10,0,0);
c.gridwidth = 15;
c.gridheight = 15;
frame.getContentPane().add(picLabel, c);
```

Comment: -1, It is always easier to modify the property of a component then it is to recreate the component and add the component back to the GUI. Anytime you add/remove components from a visible GUI you also need to revalidate()/repaint the parent container. You also need to know what layout manager is being used so you can set the constraints. This would also not work very well when you have multiple components because then you need to know where to add the component.component does this for you.