Problems reloading a JPanel image
I have a panel in my interface that will have an image inside it. Initially, it starts out empty. When I click on a button, it executes a logic that creates the image in the specific folder and then displays it. When I start the program and click for the first time, it generates the image and loads it normally in the label. However, the next times it does not update. Is there anything else to reload the label?
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
          //Salvar imagem temporaria para exibição
          String text = jTextArea1.getText();
          String export = "src/main/resources/scripts/temp/temp.png";
          String type = "png";
          File folder = new File("src/main/resources/scripts/temp");
          if(folder.exists() && folder.isDirectory()){
              Util.exec(text, export, type);
          }else{
              folder.mkdir();
              Util.exec(text, export, type);
          }
          imageReload();
    }

    public void imageReload(){
        jLabel2.setIcon(null);
        jLabel2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/scripts/temp/temp.png")));
        jLabel2.revalidate();
        jLabel2.repaint();
    }

jButton1 it is the button that generates the image and should reload
jLabel2 is the label that the image is shown in
Util.exec() It is the function that generates the new image, this is working perfectly
I tried to look for other ways to update the label, but I only saw solutions with repaint() and revalidate()

are your .class files created in the src/main/ folder or subfolder of it? Or more correctly, is that folder in the CLASSPATH used to find .class files? It seems like the image is being exported to src/main/resources/scripts/temp/temp.png and getClass().getResource( searches in the same folder where .class files are found || recommended to use ImageIO to load images (instead of ImageIcon)

You need to "flush" the ImageIcon to make sure the new image is loaded. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16866800/131872 for an example. Also, you don't need the revalidate() and repaint. Swing will automatically invoke those methods. The revalidate() and repaint() is used when you add/remove components from an existing panel on a visible frame.

Don't use that directory. The dev directories are never relevant to real apps. Also threading: you want to process your images off the EDT and synchronize the loading with it. SwingWorker is your friend and is very well documented. Util.exec is not nearly self-documenting enough
